# Is there another place to host/machine name?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, java, hostname

I have a cloned VirtualBox machine that I've asked to clear MAC address after cloning. The machine name was changed from "node01" to "new-host-7.home" and I changed to "node02" by using conventional methods (hostname, change in traditional files, etc...). All seems to be changed until my Java program get the old machine name...

My /etc/hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1       node02.home     node02  localhost
192.168.25.25   node01.home     node01
192.168.25.27   node03.home     node03
```

My /etc/hostname file:

```
node02
```

My prompt:

```
root@node02:/
```

But when I start a Java program that ask for the machine's name, I'm getting the old machine name:

```
new-host-7.home
```

Here is how I got this name:

```
InetAddress ip = getFirstNonLoopbackAddress(true, false);
this.machineName = ip.getCanonicalHostName();
```

The method:

```
private InetAddress getFirstNonLoopbackAddress(boolean preferIpv4, boolean preferIPv6) throws SocketException {
    Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
    while (en.hasMoreElements()) {
        NetworkInterface i = en.nextElement();
        for (Enumeration<InetAddress> en2 = i.getInetAddresses(); en2.hasMoreElements();) {
            InetAddress addr = en2.nextElement();
            if (!addr.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                if (addr instanceof Inet4Address) {
                    if (preferIPv6) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    return addr;
                }
                if (addr instanceof Inet6Address) {
                    if (preferIpv4) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    return addr;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I don't know if AskUbuntu is the better place for this question or StackOverflow.

TIA.

EDIT:

```
ip -o a

1: lo    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo\       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s3    inet 192.168.25.26/24 brd 192.168.25.255 scope global enp0s3\       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

getent hosts

127.0.0.1       node02.home node02 localhost
192.168.25.25   node01.home node01
192.168.25.27   node03.home node03
127.0.0.1       localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
```

Comment: This should probably be asked on [so]. Anyway, look at the IPs you have (`ip -o a`) and run `getent hosts` on them.

Comment: I meant, run `getent hosts` with the IP as argument: `getent hosts 192.168.25.26`.

Comment: @NGRhodes please point where this is a duplicate. Am I asking how to change the host name?

Comment: Ok @muru !! The old name is in there. Where I need to go to change it?

Comment: Run `grep hosts /etc/nsswitch.conf`. That will tell you the sources of hostnames in your system. You can check those.

Comment: `hosts: files dns` .... Where do I find them?

Comment: @MagnoC there is no points to be gained  from suggesting duplicates. It's just a standard behavior. My suspicion is that the hostname remains set in the kernel  during runtime, and changes only at reboot. Check `/proc/sys/kernel/hostname` file after changing the hostname. It should keep the old hostname. I suspect that's where your java program gets the old hostname. I've run `strace` on the `hostname` command and `/etc/hosts` is not being opened at all, hence - it's a kernel option

Comment: @MagnoC `files` would be `/etc/hosts`. `dns` would be the DNS server you're using. It's possible it's from some cache, if neither of those have an appropiate entry,

Comment: @Serg `/proc/sys/kernel/hostname` is already the new name: node02. @muru my `/etc/hosts` is in the question. no trace of the old name. I'll reboot my ISP router to see if is cached.

Comment: @magnoC, before firing off insults you should of read the marked duplicate and the marked correct answer which confirmed you have set the correct locations and an alternate method of how to set with and without a reboot which you could of used for debugging your situation.

Comment: @NGRhodes is not what I asked. Before seting posts as duplicate around you should READ the post.

Comment: @magnoC your titled question is "Is there another place to host/machine name?" how is that not what you asked ?

Comment: Is the title enough to you mark it as duplicate? Is this title the same question as you pointed as duplicate? Read the entire post. I don't want to set the host name. I've already done. As muru pointed, my problem is in other place and related to a Java method to get the name.

Comment: @muru I've rebooted my DSL router (my primary DNS). No changes. I'll try to change the machine's DNS server to see ...

Comment: @MagnoC If the title does not match what is asked, please edit the title to match. It would also help if you frame your text with an actual question that needs answering :)

Comment: @muru I can confirm it's a DNS caching... pointing my DNS to Googles's DNS solves the problem, that in any way is related to changing the machine host name. Cold case. NGRhodes you can continue spending your sunday reading titles to mark them as duplicated. I'll code.

Comment: @MagnoC Please check your hostname configuration - I can see as muru points out (and I have requested you to check) that you have not defined a hostname for your .26 ip address that is in use. If you correct this you should find your DNS on the network gets corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the updates to the initial question, you can see the IP command is returning 192.168.25.26 as the IP address in use, yet you have not defined a hostname on this ip address.

`/etc/hosts` needs the following entry:

```
192.168.25.26 node02.home
```

After a restart you should see the DNS on your network update and your Java code return the correct hostname.

Comment: Makes sense. Without  the own machine external IP in the hosts file, Java will ask it to the DNS server since I'm looking for `getFirstNonLoopbackAddress`...i'll try this ASAP.

Comment: Bingo! Right in the point.